# Fetch users who read the bible yesterday but not today in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hello I want to fetch users who read the chapter yesterday but not today. i have one table called user_bible_trackings that is below.

```
 user_id     date_read
   2          2021-11-25
   2          2021-11-26
   1          2021-11-22
   1          2021-11-23
   3          2021-11-25
```

My expected output is like below:-

```
user_id
  3
```

I have tried below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM `user_bible_trackings` 
WHERE  date_read = '2021-11-25' and date_read != '2021-11-26'
```

But its coming wrong output. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```sql
SELECT user_id
FROM user_bible_trackings ubt1
WHERE date_read = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_bible_trackings ubt2
                  WHERE ubt2.user_id = ubt1.user_id AND
                        ubt2.date_read = CURDATE());
```

Note that I chose to use `CURDATE()` to represent today.  You could continue to hard code dates in the above query and it would work, but `CURDATE()` is more flexible.